# Qt QML nested listview, weird scrolling behaviour

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I am having a problem concerning the scrolling behaviour of a `ListView`. When nesting lists, the inner lists were able to scroll up and down, which looks very ugly.

To avoid the problem I set the inner lists `boundsBehavior` to `Flickable.StopAtBounds`. It solved the problem and the inner lists just looks like commond delegates. However, the scrolling behaviour appears to be a little bit weird. Scrolling upwards works perfectly fine but if you want to scroll downwards, you have to move your finger in the opposite direction for at least just a millimeter. It seems like you first have to activate downwards scrolling to actually scroll upwards.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this fits your use case, but what about using repeaters instead of inner lists?

Comment: Well, that did the trick! thanks alot. The scrolling behaves as it should now.